# Keyboard submit via jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

llo,
I have a form that has two submit buttons: one accept and one cancel:

```
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="accio" value="accept" class="default" />
    <input type="submit" name="accio" value="cancel" class="cancel" />
</p>
```

I want to submit the form with jQuery using the keyboard:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=text]").focus();
    $("input[type=text]").keydown(function(e) {
            if ((e.keycode && e.keycode == 13) || (e.which && e.which == 13)) {
                $(".default").submit();
            }
            if ((e.keycode && e.keycode == 27) || (e.which && e.which == 27)) {
                $(".cancel").submit();
            }
        });
});
```

and I want the parameter accio to contain accept or cancel depending on the key pressed (I process it in the server)... It works in Firefox, but not in IE nor in Chrome. Where's my fault?

**Update**

Following @Sime's I got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text").focus();
    $("input:text").keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $("#default").submit();
            }
            if (e.which == 27) {
                $("#cancel").submit();
            }
        });
});
```

but it's still not working... I think it's with the way I submit the form... Can't I call the submit method on a "input:submit" and expect that the correct values are passed on to the controller?

Comment: @Charles Better: `input:text`

Comment: @Charles Also, you don't have to do these tests on the event object. jQuery makes sure that `e.which` is available.

Comment: @Charles Also, are you sure that you want to submit a whole class of objects?

Comment: I thought id made funny things with the submitted value... I'll try and change that and remove my tests on e.which... Thanks.

Comment: @Carles The submit() method works on FORM elements. You are trying to call it on the buttons.

Comment: Jeje, Now I see this :) I thought that if it was a "submit" button it would call the submit method on the form and pass the button value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$("input[type=text]").keydown(function(e) {
     if ((e.keycode && e.keycode == 13) || (e.which && e.which == 13)) {
        $(".default")[0].click();
     }
     if ((e.keycode && e.keycode == 27) || (e.which && e.which == 27)) {
         $(".cancel")[0].click();
     }
});
```

could you put a way to better identify the buttons.

```
$("p input.cancel")
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:text").focus();
    $("input:text").keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $("#default")[0].click();
            }
            if (e.which == 27) {
                $("#cancel")[0].click();
            }
        });
});
```

[see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/hnf5p/1/)

**UPDATE II**

this code functiona well in IE6 +, the correction is in the `stopPropagation`

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function(ev) {

  if (ev.which == 13 || ev.which == 27) {

      ev.stopPropagation();
      if (ev.which == 13)
         $("#default")[0].click();

     if (ev.which == 27)
         $("#cancel")[0].click();

      return false
  }

});
```

Comment: Still not working... I get null for the accio parameter in the first case (enter pressed) and the form clears it's values, but nothing is submitted in the second case (escape key). Thanks.

Comment: This should work. As mentioned above, you can just use e.which (jQuery makes sure it's there). JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uv79u/1/

Comment: With jQuery you should use "which", as it takes to support every browser in this way `if (event.which == null & & (event.charCode! = null | | event.keyCode! = null)) {
event.which = event.charCode! = null? event.charCode: event.keyCode;
}`

Comment: It works in Firefox and Chrome. It doesn't work in IE8... Weird.

Comment: It works with the last update. I suppose stop propagation prevents the event to continue it's normal execution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$( '#myForm' ).submit();
$( '#mySubmitButton' ).click();
```